# Not understanding a step of the proof of Lindenbaum's Lemma.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson, page 87 about the proof of Lindenbaum's Lemma.

> To prove the completeness of $J$, let $\mathscr C$  be any closed wf of $K$. Then $\mathscr C$  = $\mathscr B_{j+1}$ for some  for some $j\geq 0$.Now , either $\vdash_{J_j} \lnot \mathscr B_{j+1}$ or $\vdash_{J_{j+1}} \mathscr B_{j+1}$ , since, if it is not the case that $\vdash_{J_j} \lnot \mathscr B_{j+1}$ , then $\mathscr B_{j+1}$ is added as a axiom in $J_{j+1}$.Therefore , either $\vdash_J \lnot \mathscr B_{j+1}$ or $\vdash_J \mathscr B_{j+1}$.Thus, $J$  is  complete.

What I did  not understand is how they converted,

> either $\vdash_{J_j} \lnot \mathscr B_{j+1}$ or $\vdash_{J_{j+1}} \mathscr B_{j+1}$.

to

> either $\vdash_J \lnot \mathscr B_{j+1}$ or $\vdash_J \mathscr B_{j+1}$

Comment: $J_i \subseteq J_{i+1} \subseteq J$. So anything $J_i$ or $J_{i+1}$ proves is provable from $J$.

Comment: But if a wf is unprovable in $J_i$ , is it unprovable in $J$?

Comment: @Prithubiswas No. But if a wf is **disprovable** in $J_i$ then it is **disprovable** in $J$. There's a difference between "$\vdash\neg$" (disproves) and "$\not\vdash$" (doesn't prove).

Comment: Further to @NoahSchweber's comment, note that the completeness part of a result like this only makes positive statements about provability. It is the consistency part that makes a statement about what is not provable.